# How to find a value inside of an JSON file

Tags: node.js, json, express

I'm trying to load the names of my individual pages, by loading them from a JSON file, but I do not understand how to search for a specific value inside a JSON file.

This is running on NodeJS with Express.

What I already have for loading the JSON:

```
let pageName = "Unknown";
let file = fs.readFileSync("pages.json");
let pages = JSON.parse(file);
```

And my pages.json looks like this:

```
{
  "/login": "Login",
  "/register": "Register"
}
```

How can I search the JSON file for my page name? I already have the page URL (e.g. "/login") but I don't know how to search for the value inside the JSON file. I'm completely new to JSON so forgive me for this beginner question.

Comment: you have the url `/login` and you're looking for a match like `Login`?

Comment: No. I want to search the JSON file for the value of /login

Comment: the value of `/login` is `Login` though. Is that what you're looking for?

Comment: Yes. The name for /login to be Login is just an example. I want to search the JSON file with /login so as a result I get "Login" and if I search /register as a result I get "Register".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you have the *key* (the URL `/login` for example) and you're looking for its value in the JSON object. You can just use the `[]` operator on an object. It will give you the value if the key is there, or `undefined` if it's not. In you case it will look like this

```js
const json = {
  "/login": "Login",
  "/register": "Register"
};

const key = '/login';
const value = json[key];

console.log(value);
```